# Input validation Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, html, windows-8, winjs

In a Windows 8 Javascript app I'm trying to validate the user's input and keep the results on screen after the user presses Apply by using the following:

```
<form>
  <input id="test" type="number" min="1" max="10" />
  <button id="button" type="button">Apply</button>
</form>
```

But when I click Apply the validation doesn't work. It only works if I replace `type="button"` with `type="submit"`. The problem is that submit refreshes the page and the results disappear. What can I do?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k94nG/1/)

**UPDATE:**

I changed my code to this:

```
<buton id="button" type="submit" onsubmit="doTest(); return false;">Apply</button>
```

but it still refreshes my page.

Answer (score 0):

Form validation does not fire until the onSubmit event fires, the behavior is as designed.

One thing you could do is set the for to have an "onSubmit" event, change the button to a submit type, then in the onSubmit function call the event.stopPropigation to stop the page from doing a full postback.